# Acceleration problem involving a toy rocket launching upward

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

So, I have attempted this problem several times, yet I fail to get the correct answer. My question implies that a toy rocket is basically being launched ground up, so y (height) would be 0.00 m and time is at time t = 0.00 s. The rocket engine provides constant upward acceleration during the burn phase. At the instant of engine burnout, the rocket has risen to 75 m and acquired a velocity of 10 m/s.The rocket continues to rise in unpowered flight, reaches maximum height, and falls back to the ground with negligible air resistance. The speed of the rocket upon impact on the ground is closest to ...?

Clearly, you can get an intuition that there is no starting velocity, but you are given enough information to solve this. Can you tell me what exact equation I should be using? I may be using the incorrect one.

Comment: I don't get what exactly you want to solve. What is given and what is unknown ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I left out what I was solving for, but edited my question. Basically, I am trying to solve for the velocity of the toy rocket after it reached the top and fell back down to the ground.

Comment: without knowing how high the rocket actually goes you won't be able to solve this problem...for this we could assume some conditions like air resistance which finally would slowly decelerate the rocket until its climax and of course the **gravity**

Comment: Well, you could assume that there is no air resistance and only gravity comes into play, it's just physically dubious.

Comment: Yes, the question implies to assume no air resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only consider gravity and leave out air resistance (which is physically weird for a rocket, but why not), then this can be elegantly solved (like soooo many physics problems) using conservation of energy.

If you neglect air friction, then the mechanical energy is conserved. At the moment of the burnout, your cinetic energy is $E_c = \frac{m}{2}v_0^2$ where $m$ is the mass of the rocket and $v_0=10\, m\cdot s^{-1}$, and the potential energy is $V=mgh$ where $h=75m$. At landing, the potential energy is $V'=0$ and the cinetic energy is $E'_c = \frac{m}{2}v^2$ where $v$ is your unknown.

So $\frac{m}{2}v_0^2 + mgh = \frac{m}{2}v^2$, and you may divide by $m$ : $\frac{1}{2}v_0^2 + gh = \frac{1}{2}v^2$.

Now you just have to solve numerically to find $v$.